# Prove that $\frac{1}{\beta_1}+\frac{1}{\beta_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\beta_n}=1$ has finite number of solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Recently, I have found this problem:

> Prove that for every positive integer $n$, the equation: $$\frac{1}{\beta_1}+\frac{1}{\beta_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\beta_n}=1$$
>   has a finite number of solutions in positive integers $\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots,\beta_n$.

I am trying to prove this proposition by induction: I have already shown that for $n=1$ and $n=2$ there is only one solution, but how can I go on?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction. Have a look at it,see what you find,but i think in general this problem is non-trivial.

Comment: @SoumyadipSarkar I disagree. Let $\phi(k)$ be the largest sum of $k$ Egyptian fractions that is strictly less than 1 (this can be computed easily via the greedy algorithm). Consider $\frac1{1-\phi(n-1)}$. If any of the $\beta$s are greater than this quantity, then the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{\beta_i}=1$ is impossible to satisfy. Since we have a finite bound on each $\beta$, there are a finite # of solutions.

Comment: The thing you want to prove by induction is that the equation $$ \sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j^{-1} = a$$ has only finitely many solutions in positive integers for fixed $a$ and $n$. For this we can wlog assume that $\beta_{j}\leq \beta_{j+1}$.